# Creating a Map<U, List<T>> from a List<T> where each T contains a List<U> using Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

I have a `List` of `Product`s and every *product* contains a list of `Ingredient`s.

```
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    // other code
}

public class Ingredient {
    private String name;

    // other code
}
```

I want to collect *products* into `Map` grouping them by each *ingredient*.

How can I do it by using Stream API's `collect()` and `Collectors.groupingBy()`?

```
Product p1 = new Product("1", Arrays.asList(new Ingredient("i1"), new Ingredient("i2"), new Ingredient("i3")));
Product p2 = new Product("2", Arrays.asList(new Ingredient("i1"), new Ingredient("i3"), new Ingredient("i5")));
Product p3 = new Product("3", Arrays.asList(new Ingredient("i2"), new Ingredient("i4"), new Ingredient("i5")));

List<Product> products = List.of(p1, p2, p3);
    
Map<Ingredient, List<Product>> result = products.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( not_sure_what_needs_to_go_here ));
```

The expected result should look like:

```
[i1 : {p1, p2} ,
 i2 : {p1, p3} ,
 i3 : {p1, p2},
 i4 : {p3} ,
 i5 : {p2, p2}]
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Please clear-up what you want, possibly including examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Tuple

```
@Value
static class Tuple<L, R> {
    L left;
    R right;
}
```

or a Java record

```
public record IngProd (Ingredient ingredient, Product product) {}
```

and then stream over your products flatmapping to a tuple and collect using grouping by

```
Map<Ingredient, List<Product>> result =
        products.stream()
                .flatMap(prod -> prod.getIngredients().stream().map(ing -> new Tuple<>(ing, prod)))
                .collect(groupingBy(Tuple::getLeft, mapping(Tuple::getRight, toList())));
```

when using a record change

```
Tuple::getLeft & Tuple::getRight
```

to

```
IngProd::getIngredient & IngProd::getProduct
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be achieved using by *collector* `groupingBy()` without introducing some kind of intermediary objects that will hand out a separate *ingredient* to the *collector*, instead of a collection of *ingredients*.

But it would be redundant, in the sense that it would cost the performance (object creation doesn't happen for free) and we can do better.

Instead, we can accumulate `Product`s from the stream **without transforming them** directly into the resulting `Map` perfectly fine, by making use of the *three-args* version of [`collect(supplier,accumulator,combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)).

***Note** that in order to serve as a *key* in a `Map`, `Ingredient` need to have a proper implementation of the `equals/hashCode`*.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
List<Product> products = List.of(p1,p2,p3);
        
Map<Ingredient, List<Product>> productsByIngredient = products.stream()
    .collect(
        HashMap::new,
        (Map<Ingredient, List<Product>> map, Product next) -> next.getIngredients()
            .forEach(i -> map.computeIfAbsent(i, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(next)),
        (left, right) -> right.forEach((i, prods) ->
            left.merge(i, prods, (oldV, newV) -> { oldV.addAll(newV); return oldV; }))
    );
    
productsByIngredient.forEach((i, prods) -> System.out.println(i + " -> " + prods));
```

*Output:*

```
Ingredient{name='i1'} -> [Product{id='1}, Product{id='2}]
Ingredient{name='i2'} -> [Product{id='1}, Product{id='3}]
Ingredient{name='i3'} -> [Product{id='1}, Product{id='2}]
Ingredient{name='i4'} -> [Product{id='3}]
Ingredient{name='i5'} -> [Product{id='2}, Product{id='3}]
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/usM)